# oracle sql writing merge statement inside a select

Tags: sql, oracle

Guys is it possible to write a merge statement inside a select like below for correlated subqueries

my requirement is that i have pass to each date from `top select statement` and for the each date `select statement inside using clause` should check any data exists for that date and then do insert or update

```
select date from A a where exists (

merge in to B b 
using (

)
..
..

)
```

Comment: No, it's not. What is it supposed to do anyway?

Comment: You have to explain what exact task you're trying to solve with this weird query.

Comment: @zerkms i have explained what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you just want to use the SELECT **inside** the using clause?

```
merge into B b 
using (
select ... where datecol = (select datecol from A a where ...)
)
..
..

)
```

Comment: As far as I understand his updated question, he does indeed want to move the "top select" *into* the merge statement